# Keep All Characters Before Backslash R

Tags: r, list, char, gsub

I have a list of 10 chr called data and am trying to remove everything that occurs after the first backslash but am having difficulty.

For example, here is the first string:

`Nov. 3, 2016\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO`

I only want to keep Nov. 3, 2016

I am trying:

```
gsub('\\\\\.*', '', data)
```

But it is not doing the trick.

Please copy and paste the below in R to recreate the list.

```
data <- c("Nov. 3, 2016\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", "July 21, 2016\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", 
      "May 3, 2016\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", "Feb. 24, 2016\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", 
      "Nov. 12, 2015\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", "July 24, 2015\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", 
      "May 12, 2015\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", "Feb. 25, 2015\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", 
      "Nov. 12, 2014\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO", "July 24, 2014\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tBO")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub` function would be enough for this case since the replacement would occur only once.,

```
sub("\\n[\\s\\S]*", "", x)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SxRKe6/1)

Comment: This line which you posted before editing worked very well also, sub("\\n.*", "", data)